# How to fetch messages from array of channel objects

Tags: discord.js

I've written this code that's supposed to find the messages of each channel, make sure they're not undefined, fetch 10 of them, and then send the contents of them. However, when running it, it outputs nothing, not even giving an error to work with.

```
    filtered_channel_ids.forEach(element => {
        if (typeof element.messages !== 'undefined'){
        client.channels.element.messages.fetch({limit: 10})
        .then(message => console.log(message.content))
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element` is not a property of the `client` or `client.channels` object. It is a stand-alone string.

```js
filtered_channel_ids.forEach((element) => {
 const channel = client.channels.cache.get(element); // get the channel
 if (channel.messages) {
  channel.messages
   .fetch({ limit: 10 }) // fetch the messages
   .then((
    messages // also, it returns 10 messages, not just one message
   ) => messages.forEach((message) => console.log(message.content)));
 }
});
```

Comment: After running that, it's unable to "read property 'message' of undefined, and I think it's because of trying to get the channel with a snowflake value. Is there a way to convert a snowflake back to a string?

Comment: A snowflake is a string. What do you mean?

Comment: It says get() takes a string, and returns undefined if it doesn't find anything. So I put the pieces together and assumed the snowflake wasn't a string. My bad!